# Save image as returns image with wrong resolution

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have an image that is generated by a canvas picture editor.  Inspecting the element shows 84 x 108 however when using save image as I get 300 by 150?

Comment: 300 x 150 is the default size of the canvas element. You can resize the canvas element with <canvas width=84 height=108>.

Comment: @markE You pointed me in the right direction.  Wasn't exactly what I expected to be wrong.  Thank you for answering.